# Not able to include files when use absolute path in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I am trying to use Zend_View but facing interesting issue, here is my code in controller.

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts/account/');
$view->render("add.phtml");
```

and in add.phtml I do have below code to include header..

```
<?php echo $this->render('includes/header.phtml')?>
```

but it says "script 'includes/header.phtml' not found in path 'application path/views/scripts/account/)".

while I am able to include header file in other view files.

Please advise why it is looking under absolute path in views..

KJ..

Comment: Have you thought about using layouts or view helpers rather than an html include?

Comment: Is `APPLICATION_PATH` defined before that setScriptPath line?

Comment: Yes application path is defined as controller is allowing me to go on add.phtml, issue is not in setscript path, issue is when i am including file from view..